# Algorithmic challenge: generate a list of random non overlapping squares

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, randomized-algorithms, randomness

For an undisclosed reason, I need a list of $n$ squares in a two dimensions space where each square does not overlap.

So the challenge is simply: given a two dimensional area $a$ (`topLeft: int, topRight: int, width: int, height:int`), a number of squares required $n$ and a size for each square $s$: generate a list $L$ of $|L|=n$ squares in $a$ where the following condition holds.
$$\forall q,r \in L , q \neq r \implies \textrm{no_overlap}(q,r) \land \textrm{inside}(q,a)  $$
where `no_overlap` is a function that checks if square $q$ and $r$ do not overlap given the size $s$ and `inside(q,a)` checks if square $q$ is completely inside the area $a$.

I tried coming up with a solution myself but the only thing I can find is to brute force generating a square, check if there is overlap and if not ,add it to $L$. But as one might see, this algorithm could theoretically run forever. I would need something which is guaranteed to work in a finite time and preferably be of a complexity of at most $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$. So I thought to myself, maybe I could share this with other people around the world and see what clever ideas they have in mind. I most certainly find it an interesing theoretical question to ask. The practical reason is for a Unity 3D (game) project I am making.

EDIT:
This would be a possible solution graphically illustrated for $n=7$
[image]

Comment: (Doesn't this look $height*width$ *choose* $n$?)

Comment: Why can't you just generate squares $(0,0,s,s)$, $(0, s, s, 2s)$, $\ldots$, $(0, ks, s, (k+1) s)$,  $(s, 0, 2s, s)$, $(s, s, 2s, 2s)$, $\ldots$.

Comment: Are we allowed to rotate the squares inside the area $a$? So that we can efficiently use the space...

Comment: Assuming $s$ integral too, I thought rotation doesn't me anywhere. But there are square numbers that are sums of two squares and three orientations for rectangles that size.

Comment: @Dmitry the squares need to be placed RANDOMLY

Comment: @Inuyashayagami yes the rotation of the squares is of no concern

Comment: @WouterVandenputte Did you consider packing the $n$ squares into your box and then let them walk randomly?  If you do a random walk long enough, I would assume that it would be close enough to random (you didn't say exactly what your distribution is, though).

Comment: @PålGD that's actually a good idea. So first initalize the squares in a row and then issue let's say a hundred walk cycles where each cycle makes each square do one smal step in a random direction as long as they do not collide.

Comment: The body of the post does not describe any requirements on randomness.  As such, this question is not specified clearly enough to answer (or, it is not clear enough to know how to evaluate proposed answers).

Answer (score 1):

Factor $n$ as the product of two numbers roughly proportional to the rectangle sides, adding a few units if necessary. Let $n+r=n_xn_y$.

Now fill $n_x$ columns one square large, that occupy the whole width, with free space to the right. You can space them randomly in the vertical direction. Then for every square, scanning by columns from the left, apply a random horizontal displacement that is limited to the next column. This guarantees no collision and takes linear time in $n$.

This is not "maximally random", because the columns remain separable by a vertical line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use a 2 dimensional k-d tree to store the set of free positions $(x, y)$ where the left upper corner of a new square could be chosen without overlapping the existing squares. Each node of the tree covers a region in the area $a$ and you can decorate this node with this region's coordinate and the number of free positions that it contains. At the top of the tree, you can read the total number of available slots and simply choose a random number to get the index of that slot. By walking downwards in the tree, you can find which slot corresponds to this random number, then update the tree accordingly to add a new square.

My intuition is that the amount of data contained in the tree is approximately proportional to the number $k$ of squares already chosen and that the addition of a new square should be proportional to $\log k$ on average.

Edit: I wrote a working implementation in python 3 by using a tree structure. I'm not sure about the performance for large $n$ but it could  already be measured experimentally. I didn't make any effort to balance the tree but as new squares are chosen randomly, this randomness should balance the tree on average.

Here is a link to [the program](https://gist.github.com/Gribouillis/ff7e90dc55cab6dd32e024cd722b9c49). I don't know if I can paste it in this post. It chooses randomly at most 10 squares that don't touch each other. Here is an example output
[image]

Comment: Interesting theory, but $a$ is continious so there could actually be infinite free spaces but you answer would be an acutal solution to my practical problem